# How to add a variable to a for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, counter

I would like to add a count variable to count the comparsions in a loop but in list comprehension.

Any ideas of how to do it?

```
contador_C = 0
c = [x for x in S if d<= x and x <= u (contador += 1)]                 

# this is what I'm trying to get but in a list comprehension way

# contador_C = 0
# for i in S:
#     if d<= i and i<= u:
#         contador_C += 1
#         c.append(i)
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `contador_C = len(c)` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest alternative way, simply do `contador_C = len(c)`,

if you must do that, you may use just define a new function to do that,

```
contador_C = 0
def temp(ele):
    global contador_C
    contador_C += 1
    return ele
c = [temp(x) for x in S if d <= x and x <= u] # call the function with the element
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

Method 1:

```
def filter_item(item):
    global contador_C, d, u
    if d <= item <= u:
        contador_C += 1
        return True
    else:
        return False

c = filter(filter_item, S)
```

Method 2:

```
def count_contador(item):
    global contador_C

    contador_C += 1

    return item

c = [count_contador(item) for item in S if d <= item <= u]
```

For first case, it returns generator.